# ASP.NET Grabbing Individual Items for Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

Here is my MasterPage Page_Load

```
DataTable siteParams = new DataTable();
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("siteParametersGetAll", con))
         {
             using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
             {
                 da.Fill(siteParams);
             }
         }
     }
```

Now, I want to be able to grab certain rows without using 0,1,2,3:

Here is an example row:
ID | siteParam | ParamValue
12 |   domain  | thisWebiste.com

Currently I would have to do something like this:

```
siteParams.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
```

But that can get confusing. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the primary key to your siteParametersGetAll and uniquely identify the row you want to get?

If you're wanting strongly typed stuff to work with, I recommend taking a look at Entity Framework. That would allow you to do something like this:

```
Response.Write(siteParameters.Id);
```

Comment: This table I'm making will have numerous rows and sometimes have nothing to do with each other. I want to be able to do something like 'siteParams.domain' and get the row where the siteParam value is domain and get it's value.

Comment: So pass the domain into the proc, and make your proc like this: `SELECT * FROM SiteParams WHERE Domain = @Domain`. That will get you a set of rows all of which have the domain you specified. Is that what you're looking for? This still won't get you the "siteParams.domain" notation you're looking for though...for that you either need EF or to roll your own strongly typed solution.

Comment: Nah that won't get me what I need. I just watched a vidoe on EF and it looks very similar to a DataTableAdapter?